# 3D hidden surface removal in Object Space

Tags: algorithm, 3d, vector-graphics

I have a problem statement for which I want to know if the solution is possible. I have several 3D models which interlock with each other, and the interlocking parts are very intricate. I want to remove those intricate surfaces because when the product is assembled those surfaces are out of sight none the less. All I have is the wavefront obj file to work with and I should delete of divide the faces that will be hidden programmatically. So the end product should be an obj file that will render into an assembled product with data leading to the interlocking surfaces completely removed, which algorithm will suit the best and how should I approach this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to come up with a frostum culling algorithm to manually remove the stuff you can't see, I think a better approach would be to look into the code of when you render your Object (ex in OpenGL) there are libraries included to only render things viewed in the current perspective.

But if you really want to proceed with algorithms I suggest you readup on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum_culling

Comment: But all those Algorithms hide surfaces during rendering of the model. I want to do something prior to that. Using the wavefront obj file data I want to delete face and vertex information of the points, edges and facets that are enclosed within.

Comment: For example: Consider the 3D model of a pen. so the pen has a body and a cap, but when the cap is closed the part of the body is hidden with in. Now I will be displaying the pen with the cap closed and never open, so its safe to delete all data relating to the part of the body within the cap. and this should be done mathematically even before rendering. The program will take a obj file as input and give  a obj file as output.